# Tilling window manager written in Python

Tags: python, software-rec, window-manager, tiling-wm

Is there any tiling manager like XMonad but written with Python?
I think Haskell was too hard for me. But I know python a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are intending on creating XMonad extensions you shouldn't need much Haskell.

Looking through my xmonad.hs almost everything in there is either an import statement (which looks exactly the same as in python), or copied from other configs. So if you start with the default config and fiddle with things you should be fine.

If you do need to extend it yourself you could also look for window managers with python bindings, e.g. i3 has [this](https://github.com/ziberna/i3-py).

Answer (score 1):

Python has pretty sketchy looking xlib support -- [e.g this](http://python-xlib.sourceforge.net/)-- so I would not have thought so.

However, perusing [this list](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Comparison_of_Tiling_Window_Managers) reveals there's a least one, [qtile](https://github.com/qtile/qtile).  The arch linux wiki has [a bit of an introduction](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Qtile), since there doesn't otherwise appear to be one online (i.e., it will probably be useful to you regardless of whether you use arch or not).

Comment: okay, thank you. i'd like to try qtile instead of xmonad. more familiar with python